# Supabase Auth automatically logs out, when cookie gets set

Tags: next.js, supabase

I can't login anymore, when I set a cookie in my next.js middleware. Supabase logs the user in, but right after that the session is deleted. When I remove the line with the cookie setting everything works as expected.

Why is that?

The supabase code is the default for [@supabase/ssr](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs).

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next()

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return request.cookies.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
        },
      },
    }
  )
  const session = await supabase.auth.getUser()
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  // If there's no session and the path is not public, redirect to the login page
  if (!session.data.user && !['/login', '/auth/callback', '/register', '/_next'].includes(path)) {
    response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/register', request.url));
  } else if (session.data.user && (path === '/login' || path === '/register')) {
    response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }

  // this line breaks the code
  response.cookies.set("test", "test");

  return response
}
```

I tried to set a cookie, to save some data before the user is logged in. Afterwards I match that data to the logged in user. I was expecting to be still be able to login. Unfortunately the user gets logged out directly, without seeing the page after the login.

Comment: I think you might be overwriting the cookie that the supabase package sets. Maybe log out a `response.cookies.getAll()` to see how your code affects this. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#getall